# django have global variable to use in seprate html and text files

Tags: django

I've used [postman](https://bitbucket.org/psam/django-postman/wiki/Home) and everything is ok. It uses a `.txt` file containing mail body. Several apps uses this file. I want each of them to have a variable in this file containing an address. I mean this file has a line like this:

```
U can see the message from this address:{{address}}
```

and I want to have different addresses. I tried to send this variable in `views.py`:

```
return render_to_response('PersonHub/index.html',{'address':'azhans.net'},context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

but it didn't work. Any suggestions?

Comment: how the `.txt` file is included in the `PersonHub/index.html`?? are you using `{% inlcude file_name %}`??

Comment: I don't know It's within postman.I think It is rendered in views.py

Comment: You have to define this `address` variable in your project `settings.py` and the overwrite the `postman` url's to include this variable in extra_context.

Answer (score 2):

You can define your custom context processor to include extra variables in the RequestContext which will be available in all templates to use.

**my_context_processor.py**

```
def my_func(request):
    return {'address': 'azhans.net'}
```

and in your `settings.py` file add this to your `TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS`

**settings.py**

```
TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS = (
    #some previous context processor
    ....
    'your_app_folder.my_context_processor.my_func'
)
```

Comment: so U mean for each app I define a context processor with the same name?

Comment: it depends on you, either define context processor for each app separately or just define a single context_processor

Comment: I think I should define it for each app.cause each of them have different address.

Comment: I will suggest you to have one context processor and have multiple address variables available e.g. `address_app1`, `address_app2` and use those variables where you want to use them.